# How to manually cause a signal of another control to emit?

Tags: c++, qt

I wanted to know if its possible to emit some specific signal through coding .. For example, I want to emit another button's clicked event without the user actually clicking that button .. can do I do this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could call that other button's [click](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#click) function. It will emit the clicked signal.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of **emitting the signal by yourself** and connecting it to the slot, **why cant you call the slot directly**? Slots are just like other C++ functions, in the sense that you can call it directly. I don't see any reason where you have emit a predefined signal (like `clicked()`). **Just call your slot directly**.

Comment: Sometimes you would like to access the sender() in the slot. That doesn't work when invoking the slot directly

Answer (score 1):

if you set an action to the button, you can also simply call the action to be triggered. Just use `action_of_the_button->trigger();`!

Answer (score 0):

Signals are internally implemented as C++ protected member functions, so I'd advise against doing so. (They are public in Qt 5, though it's still not recommended as a general solution.)

Answer (score 0):

Qt, throught the moc, implement the emit keyword, that allow you to emit signals throught coding.

If the Class that you are using doesn't provide a method for emit some signal, you can Subclass it, and implement a function that does it yourself. But I must say that I had never done this for "normal" signals. Only did it when I defined my own signals in some class extension.

Answer (score 0):

to emit a signal you just write

emit signalName(param list);

```
#include <QObject>

 class myClass : public QObject
 {
     Q_OBJECT

 public:
     myClass (QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent) { }
     void foo();

 signals:
     void mySignal(int param);
 };

void myClass::foo() { emit mySignal(5); }
```

read more at http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html

you can also connect a signal to another signal so you can connect mysignal to the buttons clicked signal and when your signal is emited the clicked signal will also be emited see 
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#connect